# Number of permutations of the lexicographically smallest string

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm finding the number of permutations of the lexicographically smallest string.

For example, `bbaa` now the lexicographically smallest string is `aabb`
So, the permutations are,

`(1,2,3,4), (2,1,3,4), (1,2,4,3), (2,1,4,3)` which is 4.

My idea for it (in python) was to find the smallest string (basically sort it into a string) and then, creating a counter which stores the count of each character.

Since, we don't need a string which becomes lexicographically larger, we can only swap the same characters.

Like, `aaabbbcc` so, a has 3 places, b has 3 places and c has only 2.

Which makes the number of permutations possible, `(3*3*2)`

And this can be implemented by multiplying the values of counter. But this approach is missing out on something important because, obviously, it doesn't pass. And I found a string, which deviates this approach:

`hjkegfghjkdcoiuyg`

**Length:** 18

**Sorted:** `cdefggghhijjkkouy`

**Counter:**

`Counter({'g': 3, 'h': 2, 'j': 2, 'k': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'i': 1, 'o': 1, 'u': 1, 'y': 1})`

EDIT:

So according to my algorithm, the answer should be 24 as mentioned above. But the actual answer is '48' which is twice and I tried to figure out some relation or maybe a silly mistake, but there's no silly mistake.

Comment: In what way it deviates from your approach?

Comment: "obviously, it doesn't pass" I think it's only obvious to you... [ask] [mre]

Comment: Yes. Let me add that sorry

Comment: Compiler. In the expected correct output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to multiply the factorials of the character counts. This is because 3 same letters creates `3! = 6` permutations:
`(1,2,3) (1,3,2) (2,1,3) (2,3,1) (3,1,2) (3,2,1)`

With this example, `3! * 2! * 2! * 2! = 6 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 48`.

Answer (score 1):

Counting permutations is done with factorials. Your answer should be `3! * 2! * 2! * 2!`